# How should I detect objects in close proximity for interaction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to make my character in Unity3d interact with objects that are in front of her. After trying multiple solutions and become more familiar with them I'm lost.

I've attempted using a trigger collider attached to & in front her, however triggers give issues depending on which object is moving. If the trigger itself is moving and causes the object to no longer be within it's bounds, OnTriggerExit is often not called. If I'm not mistaken the same problem occurs if the object within the trigger is destroyed.

If the trigger is on the object she's interacting with, then she could be facing backwards and still interact with it. The trigger on the stationary object would also have to be an area on every side of the object, so she could be adjacent to the object without actually facing it or very close.

Raycasts seem like a good solution, however they are of course very narrow. Wondering if there's anything I have missed.

Thanks for any assistance or opinions on the best option.

Comment: Just a thought since I have only a little game dev experience, but maybe it would look something like a second collision detection hitbox applied to the character?  So you would have the character's hitbox, then you would have a second hitbox that would be like a big, invisible sphere around her which you could use to trigger 'proximity' events?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is what I'm referencing in my second paragraph. The problem arises from Unity's triggers being meant to be more or less stationary. If certain objects move while the other doesn't, the methods of Enter, Exit etc may not be called.

Comment: I just whipped a raycast up that is working fairly well. I'm wondering if I'm missing a work around in terms of triggers, if there's a work around for raycasts being lines essentially instead of box zones, or if there's an entirely separate solution.

Comment: I think you're right to use triggers. It's a little unclear what your setup is and what you mean by "triggers give issues depending on which object is moving".

Comment: Thanks. Edited for clarity on why triggers haven't been working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Since you noted that a `RayCast` can be a bit narrow, my suggestion is to use a [`Physics.SphereCast()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) in front of the player. Rather than checking along a line, it basically checks in a capsule-like space along the specified direction.

The method uses a fairly similar syntax to `Physics.RayCast()`. Here's an example usage:

```
Vector3 origin = transform.position;
float sphereRadius = 1.0f; // Change this as needed depending on tolerance you want
Vector3 direction = transform.forward;
RaycastHit hitInfo;
float maxCastDist = 5.0f; // Change this as needed depending on how close the object must be for interaction

if (Physics.SphereCast(origin, sphereRadius, direction, out hitInfo, maxCastDist)){
    // Logic for checking whether object hit is interactable, etc using hitInfo.
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I never knew SphereCast existed. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Raycast is a good solutuion but yes they are very narrow. But NOT BoxCast. You can send a box ray from a position on a direction. With setting size of box. Think it like too many parallel rays from character.
On the other hand, there is also SphereCast. You should choose which one is better for your program.

I think this solves your problem. And look this pages for references to this methods.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.BoxCast.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html